# Rails 5 - set field value when empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I want to add a value to a field if it is empty when the record gets created. It should take the name of the file ( attached to the record.

I tried adding below code to the controller, yet that doesn't do it. How can/should these kind of action be done in Rails 5?

```
def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)

    if @document.update(document_params)
        unless @document.name.present?
            @document.name == @document.file_file_name
        end
        redirect_to @document
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: You are doing comparison, but here you have to assign it. Change == to =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.attribute`

Add callback to model `before_save :set_field_name` and added a method:

```
def set_field_name
  unless self.name.present?
    self.name = self.file_file_name
  end
end
```

Comment: can be shortened to oneliner `self.name = file_file_name unless name`